# Entire file conflicting in git after first two lines

Tags: git, github

Between myself and another programmer who are working on the same project we consistently have a problem with git where we will commit a few changes to a specific file, push the changes up, and when the other pulls down the entire file is conflicted. It only happens with one file in our repository.

Also we noticed in github when you view that file it only shows the first two lines. However when you view it as raw it contains the entire file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on Windows if so perhaps the file has Unix end of line markers which things like notepad see as one line. So you probably do see the whole file but you need to scroll to the right to see the other lines.

You can set git to convert line endings. From [github Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)

> The `git config core.autocrlf` command is used to change how Git handles line endings. It takes a single argument.
>
> On OS X, you simply pass input to the configuration. For example:
>
> ```
> git config --global core.autocrlf input
> # Configure Git on OS X to properly handle line endings
> ```

On article is from [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html)

Comment: That could very well be it. We both normally work on OS X but my partner has a few times worked on it in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that file somehow has an embedded NUL character? By your description of the formatted file view on Github being truncated, it sounds like that might be possible. I'm not sure what the internal merge in Git does when it encounters a NUL character.

If you have `hexdump` on OS X that will help, otherwise try `od` with a suitable set of options.